# Grub not loading latest kernels. Newest kernel not in list

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel, updates, 23.04

After updating, the latest kernels get downloaded and installed. However they do not appear in the grub list of kernels. Some older kernels that have been deleted appear instead.

I've tried a lot of the suggestions online with no luck.

```
sudo update-grub2 

Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.2.0-24-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.2.0-24-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.2.0-20-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.2.0-20-generic
Found memtest86+ 64bit EFI image: /boot/memtest86+x64.efi
Warning: os-prober will be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Its output will be used to detect bootable binaries on them and create new boot entries.
Found Ubuntu 23.04 (23.04) on /dev/nvme0n1p3
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...
```

```
    ls -l /boot/
    
    total 197696
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   276283 Apr  6 08:33 config-6.2.0-20-generic
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   275984 Jun 16 11:07 config-6.2.0-24-generic
    drwxr-xr-x 3 root root     4096 Jan  1  1970 efi
    drwxr-xr-x 5 root root     4096 Jun 29 17:45 grub
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       27 Jun 28 16:31 initrd.img -> initrd.img-6.2.0-24-generic
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 77057438 Jun 17 13:05 initrd.img-6.2.0-20-generic
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 79567659 Jun 28 16:31 initrd.img-6.2.0-24-generic
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       27 Jun 29 15:49 initrd.img.old -> initrd.img-6.2.0-20-generic
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   138712 Feb 11 12:16 memtest86+ia32.bin
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   139776 Feb 11 12:16 memtest86+ia32.efi
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   144312 Feb 11 12:16 memtest86+x64.bin
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   145408 Feb 11 12:16 memtest86+x64.efi
    -rw------- 1 root root  8146863 Apr  6 08:33 System.map-6.2.0-20-generic
    -rw------- 1 root root  8152253 Jun 16 11:07 System.map-6.2.0-24-generic
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       24 Jun 28 16:31 vmlinuz -> vmlinuz-6.2.0-24-generic
    -rw------- 1 root root 14524456 Apr  6 08:35 vmlinuz-6.2.0-20-generic
    -rw------- 1 root root 13854856 Jun 16 12:43 vmlinuz-6.2.0-24-generic
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       24 Jun 29 15:49 vmlinuz.old -> vmlinuz-6.2.0-20-generic

The list from grub is given below.

[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOj38.jpg

If you check from the list in /boot, the "oracle" and "lowlatency" kernel have been removed. Yet they still appear in the grub list. The "6.2.0-24-generic" kernel is however missing in grub even though it's in /boot and is installed.
```

Comment: Do you perhaps have another Ubuntu installation on your system?  If so, maybe it is the one which installed grub, and needs the update-grub run.

Comment: Yes I do. I'll try that.

Comment: Thanks. That was the reason. It is now fixed.

Comment: You may answer your own question, and accept it (maybe after a delay). Helping others and gaining some reputation in the process.